# Извлечение содержимого из HTML регулярным выражением preg_match

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть некоторая страница. Как составить регулярное выражение, чтобы вырезать все из

```
<div class="post_body" id="p-74495559-1">
....
</div>
```

Примерно такая страница.

```
<div class="post_body" id="p-74495559-1">
<div class="assd"></div>
<div class="aaaaa">
</div>
<div class="asasas22">asdasdasd</div>
</div>
```

Вообщем, страница эта с раздачи [rutracker.org](http://rutracker.org). Мучаюсь целый день.

Comment: скрытая реклама трекера, подобные вопросы уже миллионы раз разжеваны во всех ракурсах

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В данном случае регулярные выражения будут только обузой. А что, если внутри контента будут  теги div? И их количество постоянно меняться (типично для какой нибудь страницы форума).

В этом случае куда лучше применять парсеры. Для питона это beautifulSoup. Для php есть подобное - [simplehtmldom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/). Загрузили, построили дерево. А дальше как по xml'ке. Правда иногда html может быть битый. В этом случае как раз нужны регулярки - удаляем плохой кусок. А потом парсим парсером.

Comment: ну это само собой, самый первый вариант, который может быть. Но задача стоит в том, что бы составить рег. выражение.

Comment: скажем так. под конкретный html составить можно. Но вот универсальный - иногда бывает очень сложно. очень.

Answer (score 1):

Регулярным выражением это делается ничуть не сложнее, чем любым другим способом.

```
$text=<<<HEREDOC
<div class="post_body" id="p-74495559-1">
<div class="assd">rt</div>
<div class="aaaaa">
</div>
<div class="asasas22">asdasdasd</div>
</div>
HEREDOC;
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
$re="/(?=\<div class=\"post_body\" id=\"p-74495559-1\">)(<div[^>]*>(?:(?:(?!<\/div>)(?!<div[^>]*>).)*|(?1))+<\/div>)(?<=\<\/div>)/is";
preg_match_all($re, $text, $arr);
echo htmlspecialchars($arr[0][0]);
```

Собственно на выходе получим то, что и хотим.
Ограничение по выражению:
В атрибутах тэга div не допускаются закрывающие уголки (это ограничение можно убрать, но тогда выражение станет окончательно сложным и непонятным).